# Check for installed program for remote machines does not work

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check if a specific program is installed on a remote machine.
The function for that works just fine on a local computer but not remote
I tried by opening a session and run the function in that session but I don't get the correct value.

What did I do wrong?

```
Enter-PSSession $b
Is-Installed ( "BigFarmNet 3.3.0 -rc1" )
Exit-PSSession

function Is-Installed( $program ) 
{
    $installed = ""
    if ((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture = "32-bit")
    {
        $installed = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
    Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$program*" } ).Length -gt 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $installed = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
    Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$program*" } ).Length -gt 0;
    }
    return $installed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `Enter-PSSession` in a script. It's only used in the console.
If you want to use a session in script you need to use `Invoke-Command`

Example

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "YourComputer" -ScriptBlock {
#YourCode
}
```

You can also use the `-Session` parameter for `invoke-command` if you have already created a pssession

**EDIT**

If you want to use your local function you can do it like that:

```
Function Test($value) {
 Write-Host "Variable value $value"
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "YourComputer"  -ScriptBlock ${Function:Test} -ArgumentList "YourParameterValue"
```

Comment: I tried using invoke now but now get a command not found exception. I put only the function call in the script block. Do I need to put in the complete function there?

Comment: For me it's working. Are you sure you wrote the function name correct? Did you do it the same as my example?